# VBA macros code

Tags: vba, excel

I would like integrate two macros code in to one. The first macros code is used to find the exact number of rows in a specific column. The second macros code is used to do a certain set of changes in the worksheet. I need the result of the first macros code to automatically be inserted in the second macros code. ( basically where the range is defined)

Macros code 1

```
Sub sbLastRowOfDColumn()
    'Find the last Row with data in a Column
    'In this example we are finding the last row of column D
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    MsgBox lastRow
End Sub
```

Macros code 2

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "variable1"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "gdgs"
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A360"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    'need the result of last row at the place of A360
    Range("A2:A360").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-1034
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dgdgsg"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "gdsgsdgsd"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "sdgsdgsfh"
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dgsdgsgs"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "url"
    Range("G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,M:M").Select
    Range("M1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dgdfggsdgh"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "dgsdgdshshdh"
    Range("D2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D360"), Type:=xlFillDefault

    'need the result of last row at the place of D360
    Range("D2:D360").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-984
End Sub
```

Comment: You can either change macro1 to a function for use in macro2 or just move code from macro1 to macro2 then use `lastRow` in place of D360.

Comment: Just to be clear, use the `lastRow` in place of the **360** in D**360** like `"D2:D" & lastRow`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the first sub into a function. Functions return values, whereas subs just run procedures.

```
Function sbLastRowOfDColumn()
'Find the last Row with data in a Column
'In this example we are finding the last row of column D
Dim lastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
End With
 sbLastRowOfDColumn = lastrow 'this line sets the value that the function will return.
End Function
```

Then, anywhere in your second macro that you need this value, instead of the number, just put `sbLastRowOfDColumn`. For example:

`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & sbLastRowOfDColumn)`

Comment: `Sub` can return values to objects passed `ByRef` :)

Comment: @DavidZemens - but they cannot be concatenated into a string construction. The variable can be altered with a call to the helper sub procedure and the variable would have to be part of the range address' string construction.

Comment: Correct @Jeeped I was just adding the comment for technicality's sake.

Comment: @DavidZemens -No worries. I'm just trying to maintain complete clarity given the entry level of the question. Too easy to cause confusion when a user is just starting out.

Comment: Actually that's a new one for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't clear on what you want to accomplish. You put a values into A1 then immediately `.ClearContents` on the entire column A. There are other examples of this put-a-value-erase-a-value coding. I get that you recorded it, but you need to step through it and remove the lines that do nothing. Possibly, reorganize the steps that you need to accomplish and re-record it.

Here is my attempt at cleaning up your code. I've commented a few spots that look like trouble.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lr As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

        .Columns("A:A").ClearContents
        .Range("A1") = "gdgs"
        .Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "6"
        .Range("A2:A" & lr).FillDown    '<~~see how lr is used

        .Range("B1") = "dgdgsg"
        .Range("C1") = "gdsgsdgsd"
        .Range("D1") = "sdgsdgsfh"    '<~~this gets cleared further down

        .Columns("E:E").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Range("E1") = "dgsdgsgs"
        .Range("F1") = "url"

        'i'm not sure if these columns are correct as you deleted column E:E above
        'and shifted everything left one column
        .Range("G:G,H:H,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,M:M").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        .Columns("D:D").ClearContents
        .Range("D1") = "dgdfggsdgh"
        .Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "dgsdgdshshdh"   '<~~maybe use .Range("D2").Formula for regulat xlA1 style formulas
        .Range("D2:D" & lr).FillDown    '<~~see how lr is used
    End With
End Sub
```

As you can see, there is no reason to use the `.Select` process that the macro recorder uses. The code that the macro recorder supplies is very verbose and can almost always be trimmed down to what is actually necessary.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: *It really isn't clear on what you want to accomplish.*  I'd wager this is because Macro Recorder :)